# Transfering user name and password data from one login page to another login page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey am just curious to know if this can be done! I want to make a page that takes user name and password, and on submit, transfers the exact data right into the login form of a website(eg google, yahoo, facebook etc etc) and submits it right away. Please tell me how this can be achieved!

Thanx in advance!

Comment: i would say that this is not possible, due to being XSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without installing plugins to enter the data and submit, no. You can't execute your script on a site from someone else. That would be too risky security wise.

Comment: Just to add, you may be able to achieve this via a browser extension, but in javascript? No.

Answer (score 0):

Create private encryption method encrypt username and password save that as cookies and than to access your cookies and than decrypt those cookies again.

in short make use of cookies and if you neeed security care private encryption/decryption method.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are probably going to be your best bet. It might be difficult to port them from one page to another except these are webpages you have designed yourself and have declared variables to auto-fill the text-boxes.

Another approach will be to modify the code of these pages (if you have access to them) and use PHP and Ajax to connect to a database e.g a MySQL database (could be a database like Xampp running just on your local machine) and auto-fill the text-boxes.

Check this guide, it is a little similar to what i think you are trying to achieve

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp